# pandas dataframe return wrong column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe named `results`, the `to_csv()` function returns the following:

```
data,endAt,sn,startAt,type
{},"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T07:16:47.085000'}",1c11020003,"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T07:10:35.859000'}",loss
{},"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:10:46.016000'}",1c11020003,"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:04:34.957000'}",loss
{},"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:28:16.712000'}",1c11020003,"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:21:53.127000'}",loss
{},"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T07:16:47.085000'}",1c11020003,"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T07:10:35.859000'}",low_current
{},"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:10:46.016000'}",1c11020003,"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:04:34.957000'}",low_current
{},"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:28:16.712000'}",1c11020003,"{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:21:53.127000'}",low_current
```

Now if I iterate over each rows and print the values

```
for i, r in results.iterrows():
    print("======================================")
    print(r)
    print(r['startAt'])
    print(r['endAt'])
```

it shows:

```
....(skip some lines)
======================================
data                                                      {}
endAt      {'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:28:16...
sn                                                1c11020003
startAt    {'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:21:53...
type                                                    loss
Name: 2, dtype: object
{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:21:53.127000'}
{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:28:16.712000'}
======================================
data                                          {}
endAt      {'iso': '2019-01-07T07:16:47.085000'}
sn                                    1c11020003
startAt    {'iso': '2019-01-07T07:10:35.859000'}
type                                 low_current
Name: 3, dtype: object
{'iso': '2019-01-07T07:10:35.859000'}
{'iso': '2019-01-07T07:16:47.085000'}
```

In another word, the `startAt` and `endAt` columes sometime returns `{'iso': '2019-01-07T07:16:47.085000'}` instead of `{'__type': 'Date', 'iso': '2019-01-07T08:21:53.127000'}`.

How come?

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out. Turns out the dataframe was partially constructed mistakenly, althought I am still confused how this error throws.